# Are users supposed to be able to delete targets of same-user duplicate closures?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

Twice now, I've noticed that, after I've closed a question as a duplicate of another by the same user, the user has deleted the original question. This apparently has no effect on the closed question, as it still displays as closed, and no answers can be posted to it.

As far as I know, normal duplicate targets can no longer be deleted by regular users; only by moderators, staff, or the Community user. I would think this should apply across the board, regardless of the post's owner.

This seems like a bug, but I've refrained from tagging this question as such for now, in case I've missed relevant information in my searches. I've been unable to find any meta posts concerning this specific scenario.

Comment: if this indeed happens (hard to believe without seeing example links to deleted dupe targets), it is most definitely a bug because [feature description at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239597/165773) sounds straightforward: _"If a user (moderator or any other user) votes to delete a question that has duplicate questions linked to it, their vote should not go through..."_

Comment: One just happened today, ~6-7 hours ago, but the user just recently "fixed" it themselves, apparently, in that they deleted the closed question, and undeleted the original. I'd have to do screenshots of the newer one for the <10k users, but I can't right this minute. Newer: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46131759. Original: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46111657. I closed the newer one >6 hours ago, and you can see in the timeline for the original that the user deleted it in that time.

Comment: It doesn't seem so wrong. The system draws a distinction here between ordinary duplicates and self-duplication. You can see this in the notice it posts at the top ("exact duplicate"). Surely the point of marking self-duplication is to get the OP to delete one, and isn't that what the OP is doing? Actually one usually wishes the OP would delete both. Surely it shouldn't matter which one the OP deletes (first)?

Comment: @matt If that's true, then something's still broken, because, as mentioned, if the target is deleted, the closed question remains closed, effectively preventing the user from getting answers on either one. Newer users aren't likely to understand that, and though we might not really care, I'd imagine that's not the intended outcome.

Comment: Why should the original question be pinned to life? The OP is right to delete it. The closed duplicate will be autodeleted after a while too, and no harm done.

Comment: @matt Except possibly to that user. Honestly, I'm in the "don't really care" boat, too, but it's just bad UX. Like many of the bugs reported here, this does not/will never affect me personally. I'm just kinda pointing it out.

Comment: If a question gets deleted, shouldn't any closed duplicates pointing to it be reopened?

Comment: I think what @matt was getting at is that the ideal outcome in most of these situations (unrelated to the duplicate closure but rather to the fact that users who self-duplicate tend to self-duplicate _crap questions_) is that both questions end up deleted. The easiest way for that to become a reality is to leave the duplicate in a closed state (in this school of thought the close reason doesn't matter so much as the fact that it is closed) so it can be deleted automatically by the system. The distinct lack of regard for the asker would be intentional in this interpretation.

Comment: @TinyGiant Yes, I realize that. I'm not saying I want these questions reopened, and I didn't mean to condone that in my previous comment. (I'll just delete that one, actually, 'cause it doesn't come across as I meant it to.) There are multiple problems with the current situation, though. Apart from the asker being "stuck in limbo", there's also the chance that the closed question _is_ reopened by user vote(s). Not only would that send the signal that it's OK to repeat questions, it would also negate the point of same-user dupe closure in the first place, at least partially.

Comment: @TinyGiant  The simple solution is just to not let users delete their own posts if they're dupe targets. Make it a point that they have to go back and edit the original. Furthermore, I don't really see SO being cool with "distinct lack of regard for the asker", which is part of the reason I brought this up. It's ultimately a bad experience for the asker. And, as mentioned, I don't really have a horse in this race, but I'd be pretty irritated if my Mjölnir stats took a hit because these are getting reopened. It's possible that's already happened. I've not checked yet.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that those comments were all meant in jest. I doubt that anyone truly disagrees that this is a bug and should be fixed... at least not for any rational reasons.

Comment: @TinyGiant Oh. My bad, then. I guess I'm oblivious to jest today. Shoulda hit me on the weekend.

Comment: Meta jest can sometimes be elusive. People take me seriously _all the time_.